# How should I set up lighting for a jewelry worn by a model?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting

I have a photo shoot in two weeks. Subject is a model with some jewelry from a local goldsmith, with focus on the items. The goldsmith wants b/w or sepia pictures where the items are the only "real" colored items.

As the light in the location will probably be not best, an office building with hardly any sunlight through the windows, I'm currently looking for some equipment to improve the light situation.

The camera is a D5100 with a 18-105mm kit lens, a 50mm 1.4 and a 70-300mm Sigma lens.

I thought of using two softboxes to brighten up the model due to the lack of light and eventually a ring light to cancel out remaining shadows (and I like the ring look in the eyes).

I looked through Amazon and came up with:

[this continuous-lighting softbox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074J96GRH)

and:

[this LED ring light to match](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LXDNNBW)

Is this a good setup or should I change it?

My interest is lighting jewelry worn by a model and not jewelry in general (I do have the setup for that).

Comment: Do you have experience shooting portraits?

Comment: also great way to ask this is "here is picture i like [link]. How was that lighting achieved?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have paid close attention to lighting in jewelry shops.

Usually they have lots of bright point lights. Using Christmas lights might be a cheap alternative to test such effect with a camera at home. The arrangement would be standard portrait lights plus some point lights spread around.